# concatenate, merge or join dataframe to get a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I am relatively new to pandas python and currently working on dataframes. Let's say I have two dataframes with different column headers and size. (**df1** and **df2**) I would like to concatenate them into a new dataframe while converting the dataframe header into a new row as shown in the combined dataframe. In addition, I would like to convert the initial column header names to indexes.

```
list1 = [('A', ['1','2', '3']),
    ('B', ['4', '5','6']),
    ('C', ['7','8','9'])]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list1)
```

[image: df1]

```
list2 = [('W', ['W1','W2', 'W3']),
    ('X', ['X1','X2', 'X3']),
    ('Y', ['Y1', 'Y2','Y3']),
    ('Z', ['Z1','Z2','Z3'])]

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list2)
```

[image: df2]

Desired combined dataframe output with **df2** header names appended after **df1** in the new dataframe:

[image: Correct dataframe]

I have tried using concatenate and merge in the below code but couldn't get the desired format as they specify a common column.

```
df_combined = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 0)
```

[image: Wrong df]

I tried sourcing for possible solutions from previous answers in stackoverflow but doesn't have similar solutions. Any insights guys? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert columns names to default by `range`:

```
df1.columns = range(len(df1.columns))
df2.columns = range(len(df2.columns))
df_combined = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Or:

```
map1 = dict(zip(df1.columns, range(len(df1.columns))))
map2 = dict(zip(df2.columns, range(len(df2.columns))))

df_combined = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns=map1),
                         df2.columns.to_frame().T.rename(columns=map2),
                         df2.rename(columns=map2)], ignore_index=True)
print (df_combined)
    0   1   2    3
0   1   4   7  NaN
1   2   5   8  NaN
2   3   6   9  NaN
3   W   X   Y    Z
4  W1  X1  Y1   Z1
5  W2  X2  Y2   Z2
6  W3  X3  Y3   Z3
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Much appreciated!